# Salesforce securty token and client id/sectert

Tags: api, security, salesforce, token, clientid

I have a question about salesforce and the security token.
I am changing the token, the email and password and I would like to know if I have to change also the CLIENT_SECRET and CLIENT_ID.
Are they linked with the username and pass/token?
how can I get them?

this is the piece of code:

```
define("SALESFORCE_LOGIN_URI", "https://login.salesforce.com");
define("SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID", "exempleexepleexempleexepleCLIENTID.");
define("SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET", "00000000ClientSecret");
define("SALESFORCE_USERNAME", "email@email.com");
define("SALESFORCE_PASSWORD", "password");
define("SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN", "exempleexepleToken");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CLIENT_SECRET` and `CLIENT_ID` come from the Connect App settings.  See: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_defining_remote_access_applications.htm

If the settings you are currently using are for someone else's Connected App then I'd suggest creating a new Connected App and using its values instead.